# How to download (export) an apps script add-on project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How will I download an apps-script Google Docs add-on project, which was  opened from Tools > Script editor of Google Docs.

File > make a copy of the project do not seem to be any use. since it makes online copy itself. Any alternative ways to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not develop you add-on directly in a document (I made this mistake too). Instead you need to have an independant script that you bound to a document with the options to test it as an addon ([this way](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test#create_a_test_configuration)).
Doing so you'll have the capacity to export (and import) your script with the [Google Drive rest api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export).To my knowledge there is two tools that you can use:
[gapps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-google-apps-script) writen in node
[python-gas-cli](https://github.com/joestump/python-gas-cli), a python tool (never tested it)

You should also have a look at [this post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2015/12/advanced-development-process-with-apps.html) that explain quite well how it work

Answer (score 5):

Google launched [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) last year, an official tool to import and export apps scripts projects. It works great!